# How to upload NaN values to pgAdmin? ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""

Tags: sql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

**This is the error I got:**
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""
CONTEXT: COPY Numbers-Sales-Film, line 2, column production_budget: ""

**Dataset columns + first two lines:**

```
sales_title_year,year,release_date,title,genre,worldwide_box_office,production_budget,opening_weekend,theatre_count,avg run per theatre,runtime,url
bakha satang-2000,2000,2000-01-01,bakha satang,Drama,76576.0,,,,,129.0,https://www.the-numbers.com/movie/Bakha-Satang-(S-Korea)
antitrust-2001,2001,2001-01-12,antitrust,Thriller/Suspense,17865209.0,30000000.0,5486209.0,2433.0,3.1,,https://www.the-numbers.com/movie/Antitrust
```

How do I fix the error?
I tried the code underneath. That did not work... For another dataset I had to drop the NaN values to be able to import the file into pgAdmin...

**I tried:**

````
df['runtime'].replace('', None, inplace=True)```
````

Comment: why are you replacing an empty string? what's the datatype of `runtime`?